# java xml parser with offset preserved

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I'm looking for any java parser library which can also keep the offset of each node. 
For a toy example, say i have following xml:

```
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

I want to know the span for ... if possible.
Could you anyone share with me what library can achieve, ideal in java, but other language library also acceptable. 
If not, I will use regax to manually preserve the span which may not be accurate at all across long documents.

Comment: *I want to know the span for ...* not clear what are you asking?

Comment: the span for <to>...</to> is the offset of '>' in </to> and offset of '<' in <to>. In this case, it should be 7 to 19.